# Clarification on ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand the working of ProcessPoolExecutor. I tried the below code, But getting the error:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
18     p10=Proc.submit(wait,1)
19
---> 20     Proc.join()
21     Proc.close()
22

AttributeError: 'ProcessPoolExecutor' object has no attribute 'join'

Here is what I want to do, I want to be able to run the print statement when the execution of the processes are done. Any thoughts on what I am missing

```
def wait(n):
    print(f"waiting for {n} second(s)")
    time.sleep(n)
    return("sleeping over")
t5=time.time()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Proc=ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
    p1=Proc.submit(wait,2)
    p2=Proc.submit(wait,1)
    p3=Proc.submit(wait,2)
    p4=Proc.submit(wait,1)
    p5=Proc.submit(wait,2)
    p6=Proc.submit(wait,1)
    p7=Proc.submit(wait,2)
    p8=Proc.submit(wait,1)
    p9=Proc.submit(wait,2)
    p10=Proc.submit(wait,1)
    
    Proc.join()
    Proc.close()
    
    print(p1.result())
    print(p2.result())
    print(p3.result())
    print(p4.result())
    print(p5.result())
    print(p6.result())
    print(p7.result())
    print(p8.result())
    print(p9.result())
    print(p10.result())
    
    t6=time.time()
    
    print("Time taken to run this code block is",t6-t5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the exception, just remove `Proc.join()` and `Proc.close()`. `ProcessPoolExecutor` doesn't have those implemented. You can refer [this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) for more details.

In addition, here is a way to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` with context manager `with`:

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def wait(n):
    print(f"waiting for {n} second(s)")
    time.sleep(n)
    return "sleeping over"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    t5 = time.time()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(10) as proc:
        p1 = proc.submit(wait, 2)
        p2 = proc.submit(wait, 1)
        p3 = proc.submit(wait, 2)
        p4 = proc.submit(wait, 1)
        p5 = proc.submit(wait, 2)
        p6 = proc.submit(wait, 1)
        p7 = proc.submit(wait, 2)
        p8 = proc.submit(wait, 1)
        p9 = proc.submit(wait, 2)
        p10 = proc.submit(wait, 1)
    
    print(p1.result())
    print(p2.result())
    print(p3.result())
    print(p4.result())
    print(p5.result())
    print(p6.result())
    print(p7.result())
    print(p8.result())
    print(p9.result())
    print(p10.result())
    
    t6 = time.time()

    print(t6 - t5)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using context manager for procpool, you can do batch jobs in a single map to executor,

```
 batch = [*range(0, 10, 1)]
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
      print("Initialising process executor..")
      #mapped to processpool executor
      results = executor.map(self.run, batch)

      for result in resutls:
          print(result)
```

the child processes joins when they finish their tasks.